# DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container)) Advantage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, containers

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

The function of the above code is to let the Container to manage the Controller instances.
When a web request comes to the server, the server will get a Controller instance from the Container to handler the request.

But without Container, the server will automaticlly create a Controller instance.

What is the advantage of the management of Controller in Container? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage is that you can store all of your IoC type-registrations in a single container, and therefore manage their dependencies cleanly with the IoC container of your choice (Autofac, Windsor, Unity, Ninject, etc.). If your controllers have dependencies, this lets you avoid service-locating them within its methods.

I gave an usage example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274576/how-to-use-session-values-with-unity-and-dependencyresolver) for Unity. I am using Autofac for my own project but following the same pattern.

Comment: So you mean it like this:
If we let Unity to handle the Controller, in a controller, we just only write 

  `private UserService _userService;

public UserController(UserService service){
    _userService = service;
}`

If we let the MVC Framework to handle the instance creation of Controller, we need to write

  `private UserService _userService;

public UserController(){
    _userService = new UserService();
}`

Is this all right? Is there any other advantage just like decoupling?