# Replace (and unit test) Unity Manager Session Objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, session, unity-container

I have inherited a very poorly designed ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

I have 238 lines, and 63 files that reference Unity Manager via Session object, like so:

```
UnityManager unity = (UnityManager)Session["UnityManager"];
```

The server this MVC application is hosted on had the IIS session timeout originally set at 20 minutes, which was wreaking havoc on my customers. Can you imagine the IoC "manager" object ending it's lifecycle within 20 minutes, when my users need atleast 2 hours?!?! I recently reset the IIS session timeout setting and changed it to 120 minutes...

I would now like to look into removing the UnityManager Session object from my application. I really do not understand how to do this.

I also have no unit tests in this application which really bothers me. We have looked at unit testing Unity Manager via the current Session objects but cannot figure out how to mock it.

My Questions are:

1. What is the best approach for referencing Unity Manager without a
   Session object? How do I invoke and instantiate it in my controllers?
2. Is Session object for UnityManager the preferred approach? My guess
   is no, this is horrible.
3. How can I Unit Test the current Unity Manager Session objects?

Comment: What does a "UnityManager" do? Is this your abstraction of your IoC container (A UnityContainer)? If so, you could register your container with the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator (Unity) which would set your container statically instead of per session. each session really does not need its own IoC configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I take is to replace the default controller resolver with my own which uses Unity (I've also done this with Autofac), and allows me to inject my dependencies into the constructor of the controllers (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274576/how-to-use-session-values-with-unity-and-dependencyresolver/18276096#18276096)).

I've also put a sample MVC application on GitHub here: https://github.com/agartee/Mvc4CustomIoC